# How to extend multiple displays on Windows 10 using a HDMI splitter?

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, hdmi, nvidia-geforce, splitter

I've just bought a HDMI Splitter and I want to extend, not duplicate, 2 other monitors. So after the installation I would like to use the laptop's screen and two extra monitors, all extended.

My laptop runs on *Windows 10* with a *Geforce RTX 2060*. When I navigate to "*Nvidia Control Panel -> Setup Multiple Displays*" section I am seeing only one monitor instead of two and what I've done so far is to have the laptop's display on and the other two monitors duplicated.

Is it even possible to achieve the extension or am I wasting my time here?

Comment: Please, tell us the HDMI Splitter, Moniotr and Mobo Models as well.

Comment: It's a VIVANCO HDMI - Splitter 47/80 03. To be honest I don't know what *Mobo* is.

Comment: Damn it's the motherboard, the *Manufacturer* is SCHENKER and the product is *P95_96_97Ex,Rx*. This output was yielded when entered this command `wmic baseboard get product,Manufacturer,version,serialnumber`. @jluizsouzadev

Comment: Look at **[Device Manager](https://www.windows-commandline.com/run-command-for-device-manager/)** and check out if there are something wrong with any device drive by run the comman line **devmgmt.msc**.

Comment: You're right one monitor is missing.

Comment: [Set up dual monitors on Windows 10](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/4340331/windows-10-set-up-dual-monitors)

Comment: Check out all the cables as well.

Comment: The monitor missing in device manager is an old VGA. I used a VGA to HDMI adapter for that monitor and then I plugged both the new and old monitors into the splitter. What confuses me though is that the old monitor works ok, but it's just a duplicate of the new monitor.

Comment: Which VGA to HDMI adapter model?

Comment: I've noticed that if I use the splitter only one of the two external monitors are recognized and it's the old one.

Comment: *VIVANCO 47143* @jluizsouzadev

Comment: *[Hi,

There's adapters and then there's "adapters".

You need to look for the ones that actually state that they "convert" the signal and give the product specs and whether or not they require external power to operate, not that they just have the appropriate connectors at each end.*](https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/344765/No+signal+on+monitor+-+HDMI+to+VGA+adaptor+used) by jayeff

Comment: To be fair that "adapter" of mine has external power supply. What it seems to be the problem is that using the splitter only one of the monitors connected is recognized. @jluizsouzadev

Comment: That's it. [Try to connect int that micro USB socket a power supply](http://www.vivanco.com/Homepage/Products/Audio-Video-Antenna-Cable/Video/HDMI-Adapter/vivanco-47143-hdmi-vga-adapter#prettyPhoto).

Comment: I wish it was, the power supply was connected the whole time! :) @jluizsouzadev

Comment: From your experience, is what I am asking even possible? @jluizsouzadev

Comment: In my experience, the problem seems to be the VGA to HDMI adapter, the one's imcompatible with the Splitter.

Comment: You can't use a splitter to do anything other than duplicate a signal. As far as the computer is concerned, it's one single display device and it can't send two separate signals over one cable.

Comment: I'm an idiot, I should have bought a USB to VGA adapter to connect the old screen and use the available HDMI port to connect the other screen. Then both screen would had being recognized and problem solved. It would also cost less money @SamForbis

Comment: @Themelis this helps me as well. If you don't mind put this as an answer.

Comment: I don't mind at all @10Rep